# Visual Studio 'can't contain td inside div'

Tags: html, angular, visual-studio, primeng

I am using primeNG p-table in my Angular application. I need to put this p-table in div. However Visual Studio gives a warning that I can't have td in div. But I have the whole table in it. Is it a good practice to put table into a div?

```html
<div>
    <p-table [value]="someData">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
            <tr>
                <th>some header</th>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-car>
            <tr>
                <td>some value</td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
    </p-table>
</div>
```

Comment: _"Is it a good practice to put table into a div?"_ There's no reason you can't. What version of VS are you using?

Comment: It is VS 2017 Version 15.9.7. Is it possible that as the table tag is <p-table> not <table>, VS does not see that my <td> is not directly in <div>?

Comment: @Aspram - Please include the relevant code in the question.

Comment: I think this should be reopened. Yes its fine to put a Table in a Div, however try and avoid tables inside tables and use Div's for your layout structure. I think you know the answer in that VS2017 has a warning for a **td** not inside a **table** and you can safely ignore this warning knowing you have a **p-table**. If the question is how do you suppress the warning that's a slightly different, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/in-source-suppression-overview?view=vs-2017